# How to add external module in aws lambda function?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have created a AWS Lambda Function , to putItem in dynamoDB table with API Gateway .

In the lambda function I have added a module for create userId 
UUID. I have Created Lambda function with inline code.

Now my problem is i am getting error , "Cannot find module 'uuid'"

Because Its a external module. 
So, Can anyone help me to figure out this issue. 
How I can I add this module in my lambda function and use it?

Below is my lambda function -

```
'use strict';
const uuid = require('uuid');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

exports.handler = function(event, context) {

    var tableName = "SiplAwsAPI_users";
    var datetime = new Date().getTime().toString();

    dynamodb.putItem({
        "TableName": tableName,
        "Item": {
            "userId": {"S": uuid.v1()}, 
            "timedate": {"S": datetime},
            "userName": {"S": event.userName},
            "userPassword": {"S": event.userPassword},
        }
    }, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            var response= {"response":"false",                                                        "message":JSON.stringify(err.message, null, '  '),"data":JSON.stringify(err.statusCode, null, '  ')};
            context.succeed(response);
        } else {
            //console.log('Dynamo Success: ' + JSON.stringify(data, null, '  '));
            var response= {"response":"true", "message":"Register Successfully","data":JSON.stringify(data, null, '  ')};
            context.succeed(response);
        }
    });
```

}

Here is the error-

```
{
"errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'uuid'",
"errorType": "Error",
"stackTrace": [
"Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)",
"Module.require (module.js:353:17)",
"require (internal/module.js:12:17)",
"Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:3:14)",
"Module._compile (module.js:409:26)",
"Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)",
"Module.load (module.js:343:32)",
"Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)",
"Module.require (module.js:353:17)"
]
}
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, did you use the inline editor?

Comment: Yes I am using inline editor , So I want to like aw-sdk,
how can I add another module name uuid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To include NPM dependencies, you need to use the upload functionality. For this you need to create a directory and zip it with all the dependencies included.

To simplify this process of devOps you can consider using [serverless framework](https://serverless.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, 
After go with your first solution, I have created a zip for my project with required module. Bus after uploading it ,
Its giving following error. 

{
  "errorMessage": "Cannot find module '/var/task/index'",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)",
    "Module.require (module.js:353:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:12:17)"
  ]
}

Comment: Hey, I solved it myself ,

After changing the file name - to "index.js" , Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

The code above works in Node.js 8.10 without having to upload module.

```
const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');
var userId = uuidv4();
```

Comment: In a regular node.js installation perhaps, but it doesn't work in AWS Lambda for Node.js 10.x. It yields an ImportModuleError and "Error: Cannot find module 'uuid/v4'".

Answer (score 0):

If your AWS Lambda runtime is set to Node.js 6.10, uuid module will be loaded without having to upload a .zip. If your runtime is Node.js 4.3, you'll have to bundle uuid in your zip and upload.